# Convert Rows into Columns in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a tables in this format

```
+------+-------+--------+-----------+------------+
| WBID | State | Amount | SplitCode | SplitValue |
+------+-------+--------+-----------+------------+
|    1 | AP    |     10 | W         |         15 |
|    1 | AP    |     10 | W         |         25 |
|    1 | BC    |     10 | W         |         33 |
|    1 | BC    |     10 | W         |         57 |
|    2 | AP    |     75 | W1        |         35 |
|    2 | AP    |     75 | W2        |         35 |
+------+-------+--------+-----------+------------+
```

Expected OP

```
+------+-------+--------+----+----+----+----+
| WBID | State | Amount | W1 | W2 | W3 | W5 |
+------+-------+--------+----+----+----+----+
|    1 | AP    |     10 |  5 |  5 |    |    |
|    1 | BC    |     10 |    |    |  3 |  7 |
|    2 | AP    |     75 | 35 | 35 |    |    |
+------+-------+--------+----+----+----+----+
```

Please help how to do it using Pivot

Editing the Question and putting in a detailed format -

```
Drop Table #Temp
Create Table #Temp
(
    WBID int,
    WBNM Varchar(20),
    State Varchar(2),
    TotalAmount decimal(6,2),
    SPlitCode Varchar(2),
    SplitValue decimal(6,2)
)
Insert Into #Temp
Select 1,'PR1','CT',10,'W2',5
Union ALL
Select 1,'PR1','CT',10,'W3',5
Union ALL
Select 2,'PR1','CT',10,'W4',4
Union ALL
Select 2,'PR1','CT',10,'W5',6
Union ALL
Select 3,'PR1','CT',10,'W2',6
Union ALL
Select 3,'PR1','CT',10,'W4',4
Union ALL
Select 3,'PR1','NY',70,'W2',35
Union ALL
Select 3,'PR1','NY',70,'W5',35



Select distinct
WBID,
WBNM,
STate,
TOtalAMOUNT                     ,
W2,W3,w4,W5,W8
From #Temp
Pivot
(
    sum(SplitValue ) for SplitCode  in ( W2,W3,w4,W5,W8 )
) piv;
```

Comment: You seem to be aware that pivot is required - so what have you tried? Can you show us your attempt to use it?

Comment: What is the logic used to get the final result?  You are showing final columns as `W1`, `W2`, `W3`, and `W5` but you have `SplitCodes` that don't match that?  Also how do you determine the value that is going under each column header?

Comment: @user2979235 it's bad form to change your data halfway through... In any case it looks like you already answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're looking for a dynamic approach so that you'll always get a new column for new Wx -splitcode. I know no other way than building the query dynamically:

```
DECLARE @query  nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @cols   nvarchar(max)
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(SplitCode) 
              FROM CTE 
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')


SET @query = '
Select distinct 
  wbid, state, amount,'
  + @cols + '
From CTE
Pivot
(
  sum(SplitValue)
  for SplitCode  in ( ' + @cols + ' )
) piv;
'

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Comment: Thanks Simo and every one who put their hands. It is useful. Why we need to use aggregate function?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
select WBID, State, Amount, 
max(case when splitcode='W1' then splitvalue end) as w1,
max(case when splitcode='W2' then splitvalue end) as w2,
.
from table
group by  WBID, State, Amount
```

Comment: This technically will work, but it's not a very elegant solution vs. using `PIVOT`.